# Unable to retrieve Json Information

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json

Trying to retrieve a JSON array however the page is just echoing "Null"

Here is the code that I use to retrieve the Json Variable

```
    <?php
function getSystem($address)

    {

        $data_location = "/r10database/checkSystem/index.php?theaddress=".$address;
        $data = file_get_contents($data_location);


        $data = json_decode($data);

        $system = $data->system;

        var_dump($system);



    }
getSystem("Blvd");
?>
```

And here is my code to encode my json variable

```
function changeElement(contentString,address){


var addressObject = new Array();
addressObject[0]=contentString;

var json_str = JSON.stringify(addressObject); 
var obj = JSON.parse(json_str)

  $('#insertHere').html(json_str);

}
```

Comment: That page does not seem to return any json.

Comment: How would I return JSON with the page? the javascript code that is supposed to encode the variable is the second piece of code @jeroen

Comment: You can try my php that tries and retrives the json
http://pear.coreyjansen.com/r10database/checkSystem/TestRetriveJson.php

Comment: return jsn from your php - json_encode($system); you should also set the correct header

Comment: Fix your problems one at a time, first make sure your `http://pear.coreyjansen.com/r10database/checkSystem/index.php` always returns valid json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The remote API is broken.

http://pear.coreyjansen.com/r10database/checkSystem/index.php?theaddress=200%20Scurfield%20Blvd

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "http://geoxml3.googlecode.com/svn/branches/polys/geoxml3.js". index.php:11
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token else index.php:116
Uncaught ReferenceError: initialize is not defined index.php?theaddress=200%20Scurfield%20Blvd:132
```

Comment: Ive fixed that now and the page is echoing ["man"] and still isnt working. @AlienWebguy